# Having a problem deserializing types returned by Yahoo geocoding service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, yahoo, wcf-client

I am working with the Yahoo geocoding service, a RESTful XML-based service. I cannot get the XML response fully deserialized.

I've created two classes for the result: PlaceFinderResultSet and Result. PlaceFinderResultSet correctly deserializes the simple types, but I cannot get the complext "Result" node to be deserialized - my Result property is null.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="ResultSet")]
public class PlaceFinderResultSet
{

    [XmlElement("Error")]
    public int Error { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ErrorMessage")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Locale")]
    public string Locale { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Quality")]
    public int Quality { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Found")]
    public bool Found {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("Result",Type=typeof(Result),DataType="Result")]
    Result Result { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.com", TypeName = "Result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement("quality")]
    public int Quality{get;set;}

    [XmlElement("latitude")]
    public double Latitude{get;set;}

    /** the rest of the code was omitted for brevity **/
 }
```

Here is an example of the XML I am trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResultSet version="1.0">
    <Error>0</Error>
    <ErrorMessage>No error</ErrorMessage>
    <Locale>us_US</Locale>
    <Quality>99</Quality>
    <Found>1</Found>
    <Result>
        <quality>72</quality>
        <latitude>50.000000</latitude>
        <longitude>-77.000000</longitude>
        <offsetlat>50.000000</offsetlat>
        <offsetlon>-77.000000</offsetlon>
        <radius>500</radius>
        <name>50 -77</name>
        <line1>Route de la Baie-James</line1>
        <line2>Baie-James, QC  J0Y</line2>
        <line3></line3>
        <line4>Canada</line4>
        <house></house>
        <street>Route de la Baie-James</street>
        <xstreet></xstreet>
        <unittype></unittype>
        <unit></unit>
        <postal>J0Y</postal>
        <neighborhood></neighborhood>
        <city>Baie-James</city>
        <county>Baie-James</county>
        <state>Quebec</state>
        <country>Canada</country>
        <countrycode>CA</countrycode>
        <statecode>QC</statecode>
        <countycode></countycode>
        <hash></hash>
        <woeid>12697261</woeid>
        <woetype>11</woetype>
        <uzip>J0Y</uzip>
    </Result>
</ResultSet>
<!-- gws26.maps.sp1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Sun Jan  2 12:54:55 PST 2011 -->
```

Comment: Pastebins are bad for question longevity, so I copied the sample XML directly into the question.  If you want the XML shorter, feel free to chop it up like you did with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had a go, and I got it working by...

Commenting out the `[XmlType]` Attribute completely, and.... change this line:

```
Result Result { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
public Result Result { get; set; }
```

Gah that serializer is picky!

Comment: +1 For finding the bug :) The default XML serialization requires members to be public, and that's probably the core of the bug.

Comment: @Merlyn Yep.  Since I did mark it to be serializable, it would be nice if the Framework threw some kind of an exception.

Comment: @rhooligan: It would be.  But it probably uses reflections under the covers to enumerate these values, and checking for private members would decrease perf in a well-conforming type.  People are really sensitive to reflections perf for some reason... :)  A compiler warning would be awesome, though.  One of the built-in code analysis tools in Visual Studio might catch this.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following:

- grab the output from one of your calls to Yahoo and store the XML on your disk somewhere
- then run the `xsd.exe` utility from the Microsoft Windows SDK over this file twice

Read about the [`xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) tool on MSDN - it's a great timesaver!

First run:

```
xsd.exe yahooresult.xml
```

This will turn the result XML into an XML schema - `xsd.exe` will do the best to guess what the XML schema should look like, but you might want to have a look at the resulting XSD anyway, and tweak it, where necessary.

Second run:

```
xsd.exe yahooresult.xsd /C
```

This will turn the XSD file into a C# class file which you can then use to deserialize those XML files you get back from the Yahoo service.

The resulting C# file is too large to post here, but I was easily able to deserialize the sample XML created from your link posted, and I was able to get it into a C# class generated from that XML sample file.

Also: if you have Visual Studio 2008 and you have the WCF REST Starter Kit installed, Visual Studio features a new menu item:

```
Edit > Paste XML as type
```

By putting your XML onto the clipboard and then picking that menu item, you can have Visual Studio generate a nice C# class for you that will properly deserialize that XML - very handy!

With a bit of manual work, you can get this in Visual Studio 2010, too - see [Danny Diaz' blog post on it](http://smallandmighty.net/blog/paste-xml-as-type-in-vs-2010/)

Comment: Sounds like a good plan for the next REST service I have to consume.

Comment: +1 for a good general solution.  It's always best if you can to find a tool to do code generation for you, if you're simply converting object types around.  If you don't like it's output, you can always tweak it/copy paste, etc.